# Somar valores de mesmo código

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho uma tabela que lista quantidade de compra de cada produto, por exemplo, se o comprador faz 3 pedidos de compra ele repete os pedidos e quantidades. Um exemplo disso é a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

por exemplo, o refrigerante que tem 3 pedidos de 900, eu gostaria de somar isso para aparecer 2700 entende? Teria como fazer isso no select do mysql? Ou por PHP?

Eu preferia que fosse por mysql, para dar manutenção depois me facilita. Mas em PHP eu também aceito.

Meu select:

```
$stid = "SELECT b.id, b.codigo, a.codacesso, a.seqproduto, a.desccompleta, b.quantidade, b.data_vencimento, b.data_atual, b.observacao, b.usuario, b.estado, b.loja, a.medvdiageral, a.comprador, a.preco
FROM master_datas_b a, master_coletores b 
WHERE b.tipo_acao IS NULL and a.comprador = :comprador and a.nroempresa = :loja and b.loja = :loja and estado = 'Ativo' and b.codigo = a.codacesso AND b.data_vencimento BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data1,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:data2,'YYYY-MM-DD') and b.quantidade > 0 ORDER BY b.data_vencimento, b.codigo ASC";
```

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma seja usar a função SUM() com o GROUP BY.
Ou seja, agrupe suas informações por pedidos e utilize o SUM(valor) no select de sua query. Talvez ajude: [Link](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php) Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Você tem que fazer um `GROUP BY` pelo `EAN` e aplicar um `SUM` na `Quantidade`. Para formar uma resposta exata, seria interessante você colocar seu `SELECT` e sua estrutura

Comment: coloquei o meu sql que faz a listagem

Comment: O campo que contém o `EAN` é o `codigo` ou `codacesso`?

Comment: é o seqproduto cara

Comment: ta dando erro :T

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Answer (score 1):

Isso seria um agrupamento de registros, assim como outros `SGBD` o MySql tem uma cláusula justamente para isso, que é o `GROUP BY`. Com ele você consiguirá agrupar os dados pela coluna `seqproduto`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT
    b.id, b.codigo, a.codacesso, a.seqproduto, a.desccompleta, SUM(b.quantidade) AS quantidade,
    b.data_vencimento, b.data_atual, b.observacao, b.usuario, b.estado, b.loja, a.medvdiageral,
    a.comprador, a.preco
FROM master_datas_b a, master_coletores b 
WHERE
    b.tipo_acao IS NULL and a.comprador = :comprador and a.nroempresa = :loja
    and b.loja = :loja and estado = 'Ativo' and b.codigo = a.codacesso
    AND b.data_vencimento BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data1,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:data2,'YYYY-MM-DD')
    and b.quantidade > 0
GROUP BY seqproduto
ORDER BY b.data_vencimento, b.codigo ASC
```

Veja mais sobre `GROUP BY` [aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consegui desta forma, pq estão negativando minha pergunta?

```
SELECT a.seqproduto, a.desccompleta, SUM(b.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE
FROM master_datas_b a, master_coletores b 
WHERE b.tipo_acao IS NULL and a.comprador = :comprador and a.nroempresa = :loja and b.loja = :loja and estado = 'Ativo' and b.codigo = a.codacesso AND b.data_vencimento BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data1,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:data2,'YYYY-MM-DD') and b.quantidade > 0 GROUP BY seqproduto, desccompleta ORDER BY a.seqproduto, a.desccompleta ASC
```